# when i try to add cardView as a container to TextView in ListView app Carshed?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, android-adapterview

[image]

I want to make autoCompletePlace EditText with Custom ListView 
 1- xml
activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <EditText

         android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="enter location"
        android:id="@+id/edEnterLocation"
        android:textColor="#000">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Second xml >> adapter_google_places_autocomplete

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java files
1-

```
package belalfci.googleapiplace1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ListView listView;
    public EditText editText;
    GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edEnterLocation);
        TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        CardView cardView=(CardView)findViewById(R.id.cardView);


        dataAdapter = new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.adapter_google_places_autocomplete);
            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView
            listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);



        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged (Editable s){



                }

               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                  dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());


                }


        });


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                  String  selectedLocation = dataAdapter.getItem(position);
                  editText.setText(selectedLocation);

        }
    });


    }
}
```

2-

```
package belalfci.googleapiplace1;


import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {


    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Google Places Autocomplete";
    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";
    private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCS_bFUFXJ4ni3chIVI0EvFxk231Yau2Do";
    private ArrayList<String> resultList;
    private Context context = null;


    public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(resultList != null)
            return resultList.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }


    public ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;
        ArrayList<String> descriptionList = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
            //to make suggestions for custom Country
          //  sb.append("&components=country:eg");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            Log.d("yo",jsonResults.toString());
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
            descriptionList = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());
                descriptionList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return descriptionList;
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

when I use just TextView in the Second xml it worked well But I need to add card View as a container to this TextView?

Comment: I advise to find a tutorial about how to use ListView to understand the cause of the problem, and avoid other problems with the listViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an `ArrayAdapter` and you have an edited layout (as you have), you should to use the constructor with the `TextView` id.

You are calling the construtor with wrong arguments, so change all your implementation to this:

**YourAdapter:**

```
public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int layoutId, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, layout, textViewResourceId);
        this.context = context;
    }
```

**YourActivity:**

```
dataAdapter = new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_google_places_autocomplete, R.id.textView);
```